# How good is Ding Liren in xiangqi (Chinese chess)?

Tags: xiangqi, ding

Just wonder, what is the level of Ding Liren in Chinese chess (xiangqi)?

Comment: Where have you already looked for information about this topic ? Do you have any source about Ding playing Xiangqi at all ?

Answer (score -4):

According to wikipedia he was Chinese champion in Chinese Chess: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Chess_Championship

Comment: That is the Chinese "Chess Championship", not the Chinese "Chinese Chess" Championship.